# Why is my for loop stopping before last index?

Tags: c#

I want to read 20 items but only 19 are read through console. Any idea why ?

What I'd like my code to do is :

- 1st : read the interger k from the standard input buffer (console)
- 2nd : read 20 integers into the array `int x[]`

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int k ;
    int[] x = new int [20];
    int[] y = new int [20];
    int[] yval = new int[20];
    int i;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter k value");
    k = Console.Read();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter x values\n ");
    for (i = 0; i <=19 ; i+=1)
    {
      x[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      yval[i] = (x[i] + k) % 26;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: I suspect you'll find that 20 are being read - but the first one isn't what you expect it to be, due to your use of `Console.Read()`, which is reading a single character. Perhaps you wanted `k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` there? (As a side-note, I'd *strongly* encourage you to declare variables at the point of first use rather than putting them all at the top of the method.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I think that might be the problem. I just saw k was giving a strange result. I also guess from what you just said that `Console.Read()` affected the other lines.... As for the variable declaration, it's an habit from C programming. Thanks for the advice though (I'll start working like that now)

Comment: Possibly because you are saying 'i <= 19'? I am not entirely sure, I just usually have had problems when doing that.

Comment: @KyleStankovich That doesn't make any difference at all, but `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)` certainly reads much better.

Comment: @KyleStankovich Nope. thats not the problem. Read the first comment of @Jon Skeet. `Console.Read()` is affecting in an unexpected way my code.

Comment: What makes you bellieve its only 19 values read?

Comment: @CSharpie Because I counted them when entering them in the console. Actually, the first comment is the answer. The first `Console.Read()` is the culprit. I changed it as suggested and it worked fine

Comment: @JasonKrs: Well, it's unexpected *by you*. I think if you read the documentation for `Console.Read` carefully, you'll see why it's happening, and why it *is* the expected behaviour :)

Comment: @JonSkeet  I think you should type your comment as asnwer to the question as it fixed my issue and some people as still asking why I only get 19 counts

Comment: @JonSkeet  Haha. Yes. It's unexpected by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon addressed the root of the problem in the comments, but I wanted to try to answer more fully.  `Console.Read()` will only read a single character and return an integer representing the character, probably not what you want.  Any characters after that are immediately read on the first pass, probably not what you expected.  The issue can be illustrated by inspecting the values:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int k;
        int[] x = new int[20];
        int[] y = new int[20];
        int[] yval = new int[20];
        int i;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter k value");
        k = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("k = {0}", k);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter x values\n ");
        for (i = 0; i <= 19; i += 1)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            x[i] = int.Parse(input);
            yval[i] = (x[i] + k) % 26;

            Console.WriteLine("x[{0}] = {1}", i, x[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

If you enter "12" for k, the output looks like:

```
Enter k value
12
k = 49
Enter x values

x[0] = 2
```

The first character `'1'` is saved to `k` as `int` value of 49 (ASCII value for `'1'`).  The buffer still has a `'2'` and a newline to be read.  They get read on the first pass through the loop and stored in the first element of the array.

As Jon said, you probably want `k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` instead.

Comment: the newline character is inside x[0] with the 2 ?

Comment: No, the newline is not returned.  From the documentation for [Console.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), "A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return (hexadecimal 0x000d), a line feed (hexadecimal 0x000a), or the value of the Environment.NewLine property. The returned string does not contain the terminating character(s)."